# Dimension values not visible

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas

Have created a sample ssas cube, in where it has one dimension and a measure.
Have linked dimension and measure using dimension usage tab. The scenarios is, not all dimensional values are available in the fact.
Have deployed and processed the cube.
When browsed only the dimension, the attribute is not showing all the values that are in DB, it is showing only those values that are in fact.

Got various links asking me to do full process of dimension, and it didnt work.

No matter the dimensional value is available in the measure or not, I want to see all the values when I browser only the dimension.

Any non empty property that I am missing here. Please let me know.

Comment: What are you browsing with? SSMS? Excel?

Comment: Browsing with both SSMS or Excel is giving me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a 'show empty cells' option in excel and ssms? I think you right click to enable it.